# jQuery Regular Expression (regex)

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

Anyone help with this jQuery I'm trying to pull off I can't get the regex to work

```
cj("input[id='PRE_TEXT_'(.*)'_POST_TEXT']").hide();
```

Comment: This isn't how jQuery selectors work. You'll need to use `$.filter()` and use your regex in the function you pass to it.

Answer (score 3):

You can't use regex in jQuery selectors. Use the filter function:

```
cj("input").filter(function() {
    if (/^PRE_TEXT_(.*)_POST_TEXT$/.test(cj(this).prop("id"))) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}).hide();
```

Comment: Thanks Micha James solution below has done the trick, but this will help in future.

Comment: @Generic yes James solution is better, I just left this post for future visitors who really are in need to use a complex regex.

Answer (score 2):

You can't use regex, but you should be able to use startswith and endswith.

```
cj("input[id^='PRE_TEXT_'][id$='_POST_TEXT']").hide();
```

Comment: Thanks James works perfect I should have thought of this bit new to regex.